# Does Google talk support video/audio calls on Linux (using Pidgin)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pidgin, google-talk, video-chat

I know that Pidgin has a video/audio plugin which I installed. But this doesn't seem to work with gtalk. I guess google doesn't support linux anymore?

What is happening is that when I attempt a call, I can see my self but not the other person (black screen) & the same for the other person (he can see himself but not me). Moreover audio doesn't work.

So does it work? & if so how?

Answer (score 3):

It **should** work with pidgin also. Maybe you are missing some packages as stated at [pidgin faq](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#DoesPidginsupportvoiceorvideo):

> Why can't I do a video call with the GMail client?
>
> Interoperation with the GMail client requires you to have the H264 GStreamer codec installed. You can find these in gst-plugins-ugly and gst-ffmpeg. For debian based systems that's gstreamer0.10-plugins-multiverse and gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg.

As stated in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/9222) askubuntu question you must install

`gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` and `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`

(I also installed by myself `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse`, because I read about it somewhere I don't remember)

But after installing those packages, and after restarting pidgin, I couldn't make it work at first. (Empathy works at first restart, see below).

So what I did after installing the packages to make it work (I'm not sure of which steps are really necessary, but doing them all made it work):

- Removed all accounts from pidgin (it could work just by removing the google account, but let's make sure here)
- Restart pidgin (make sure you really shutdown pidgin)
- Add the google account
- When adding the google account go to the tab **Voice and Video** ( or **Sound and Video** )
- Check the only checkbox that exists in this tab if not already checked (something about sound/silence suppression)
- Complete other account information and then save
- Profit! =D

I tested with Pidgin and definetely works with one official Google Talk client:

- From Ubuntu with Empathy I was able to video/talk with other person using Gmail's Google Talk
- Couldn't video call from Ubuntu to video/talk with Android's Google Talk client. In this test, I didn't test sound/voice. Maybe just sound/voice works with Android's Google Talk client.

---

***An alternative***

That seems to work more easily just after a restart of the program AND seems to work better with other Google Talk clients overall.

Try [Empathy](https://live.gnome.org/Empathy). (Default for ubuntu now)

I tested with Empathy and definetely works with other Google Talk clients (google ones):

- From Ubuntu with Empathy I was able to video/talk with other person using Gmail's Google Talk
- From Ubuntu with Empathy I was able to video/talk with Android's Google Talk client

Note: Remember that you need to install those same packages needed for pidgin to make video/audio work with Empathy also. ([source](https://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#Audio_and_Video_calls))